# In Scala, is assignment operator "=" a method call?

Tags: scala

As per Scala book, "Programming In Scala" -

`Scala is an object-oriented language in pure form: every value is an object and every operation is a method call. For example, when you say 1 + 2 in Scala, you are actually invoking a method named + defined in class Int.`

In that sense, what about assignment operation using "=" operator? Is that also a method? Seems unlikely, because then it has to be present in all classes or some common super class (say, java.lang.Object ?) that all classes have to inherit it from. Or is it that not all operations are really method calls in Scala?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope. Assignment operator (`=`) is a reserved word. Also the below are:

> _  :  =  =>  <-  <:  <%  >:  #  @

For a more comprehensive list refer [§ 1.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf). Some more information regarding `=` is described in `§ 6.12.4`.

So yes it is not a method call.

Comment: It is a bit surprising to also find modulo (%) operator in this list. In my opinion, it is similar to other fundamental arithmetic operators such as +, -, etc and could also have been a method too, in that sense.

Comment: @Sumit it's not `%` but `<%` a syntactic sugar for implicit view in type parameters

Answer (score 22):

A little addition to **Jatin** answer. There is one case when `=` can be considered as a method call, but actually it's just a syntactic sugar. In OO part of Scala, where ugly `var`s lives, you can write the following:

```
class Test { 
  private var x0: Int = 0
  def x = x0
  def x_=(a: Int) = x0 = a 
}
```

Then you can assign new ints to `x`:

```
scala> val t = new Test
t: Test = Test@4166d6d3

scala> t.x = 1
t.x: Int = 1
```

The last line will be desugared into `t.x_=(1)`. I think in this case, considering syntactic sugar, it's possible to say that `=` is a method call.

Comment: What did you mean by **syntatic sugar**? Does it mean scala compiler's doing magic thing behind?

Comment: Yes! That's compiler. @suud

Comment: "In OO part of Scala, where ugly vars lives" – I chuckled, but well, this kind of humor doesn't help to make the Scala community more welcoming to newcomers. but sets them on course to learn Kotlin instead.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers are correct for standard Scala, there is a variant called [Scala-Virtualized](https://github.com/TiarkRompf/scala-virtualized/wiki/Virtualized-Scala-Reference) where `=` and other control structures *are* method calls.

Comment: I really wish this project would be merged into mainline Scala. From a pure OO perspective, it makes sense to be able to implement the behaviour of `var` and `=`, more so `if`, `while` etc.