# Is it possible to overload the '=' or '==' operators to mean something apart from assignment or equality?

Tags: scala

I need to overload either the `=` or `==` to behave differently than assignment or equality. Suppose I have the code:

```
case class Col(name:String) 
def foo(col:Col, data:Any):SomeType = ??? // SomeType is another type 

val age = Col("age")
foo(age, 21)
```

I would like to provide syntactic sugar for `foo(age, 21)` as follows:

```
case class Col(name:String) {
   def ===(data:Any) = foo(this, data)
}
```

Then I can do:

```
age === 21 // works (returns SomeType)
```

What I would have liked to do:

```
age = 21 // does not work
```

or even

```
age == 21 // will not work as expected (== must return Boolean)
```

Is it possible? (prefer the `=` method)

Comment: That's the perfect way to confuse anyone reading your code. You can use slightly modified symbols instead like `:=` or `<<=`, even `≡`, etc...

Comment: Its for an internal DSL so things like `select(a, b).where(age = 21)` should make sense.

Comment: I've seen `eqs` in Rogue: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html, `===` in Slick: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html, and `==` in LINQ where it has boolean result. Your DSL looks confusing to me bro ;)

Comment: I ended up using `===`. More intuitive and Scala gives warning when I forget that and use `==` instead. Ideally, it should not even compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
scala> class A { def ==(o: Int) = "Donno" }
defined class A

scala> new A {} == 1
res2: String = Donno

scala> new A {} == "1"
<console>:12: warning: comparing values of types A and String using `==' will always yield false
       new A {} == "1"
                ^
res3: Boolean = false

scala> new A {} == new A {}
<console>:12: warning: comparing values of types A and A using `==' will always yield false
       new A {} == new A {}
                ^
res4: Boolean = false
```

or this:

```
scala> class A { def ==(o: Any, s: String) = s }
defined class A
```

but not this:

```
scala> class A { def ==(o: Any) = "Donno" }
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("Donno")
 required: Boolean
       class A { def ==(o: Any) = "Donno" }
                                  ^
```

If you override a function you can't change it's return type. You can however overload it by changing it's signature.

p.s. please don't do it :)

Comment: I'll take your suggestion and use `=!=` and `===` as in Slick. Just wanted to know if its possible. BTW slightly better workaround would be to use something like `age.value = 21`.

Comment: I also like your idea of giving individual types (`Int`, `String`, etc). Still weighing in the options to confuse users or not :)

Answer (score 1):

Possible. Look into canEqual, hashCode and equals methods.

Comment: You cannot change the return type though... So the `returns boolean` bit will not be addressed

Comment: I want `==` to return `SomeType`. So this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Jus12, won't it be too ambiguous for == to return anything other than boolean in your case?

Comment: Yes thats why I prefer `=`. I don't think its possible to overload `==` and it probably makes sense not to be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

With `==`, we can do it as described in [Aleksey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34807048/243233) (i.e., using separate methods for `Int`, `String`, etc instead of `Any`. The closest we can get to using `=` as something other than assignment is the following (based on [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19087649/243233)):

```
type SomeType = (String, Any)
case class Col(name:String) { 
  private var x: SomeType = _
  def value = x
  def value_=(data: Any):SomeType = ("hi", data)
}

val age = Col("age")

age.value = 21 // returns SomeType
```