# print string whenever variable get changed with scala macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

If I have defined a variable b `val b:B`. Is it possible to print the value of `b` each time b is assigned to a new value. Like the code below:

```
  case class B(name:String) {
  }

  var b = B("123")
  b = B("xxx")
  println(s"b is changed to $b")

  b = B("xxJJx")
  println(s"b is changed to $b")
```

I hope the code `println(s"b is changed to $b")`  be hidden in some sort of macro when I create `B` or `b`, like:

```
var b = macro_wrap(B("123"))
```

Comment: In Scala assignment operator [is not a method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086851/in-scala-is-assignment-operator-a-method-call), so def macros will not help.

Answer (score 0):

With plain `var`, you cannot do it.

The closest you can get is to create a getter-setter pair which will look like a `var` from outside:

```
object Stuff {
  private var b0 = B("123")
  def b: B = b0
  def b_=(newb: B): Unit = {
    b0 = newb
    println(s"b is changed to $newb")
  }
}
```

Then:

```
Stuff.b = B("xxx")
```

Will print the new value.

Note that the setter is a method named `b_=` which is treated somewhat specially by Scala compiler - an assignment `Stuff.b = B("xxx")` is automatically translated into `Stuff.b_=(B("xxx"))`. This works only if setter is accompanied by a getter.